# PHP Authenticate user for each page of website

Tags: php, authentication

I'm developing a website, where in most of pages user need to log in to view pages of website. What is the best way to check  if user is logged in or not, and if not redirect it to log-in page.

currently I'm using following code to do that.

```
if(!isset($_SESSION["username"]))   //I set the session when user log in and destroy when user logout
    header("location: login.php");
```

There are lot of pages and I put this code in every page. It also works well.

I want to know is there any other batter way to do this? Or what I'm doing is good way? and I don't need to change anything.

Comment: you should create a function for that and call that function on each page at the top.

Comment: You should use a framework, it would handle issues like this for you and it gives you the structure that you need so you dont repeat yourself - cakephp.org

Comment: A framework just for authentication? A bit overkill don't you think?

Comment: If you are good enough you can apply the way how frameworks are handling authentication, by your own. First you need to think of a better architecture

Comment: As of now I'm only good at pure PHP and don't know any framework. I've to develop this website quick so I don't have time to learn framework for this website, but i can learn and then use it in next website.

Answer (score 2):

Simple Solution is create a file named as `session.php`

include your session checking code into that. Like,

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['YOUR_VAR'])) {
    header('Location: login.php');
}
```

include this file into all your pages, with `include` OR `require`

I prefer require function. example in your home.php file at the beginning of page write,

```
<?php
    session_start(); //don't forget to do this
    require('session.php');
?>
```

> NOTE : In future if you enhance your session checking code you just
>   have to change one file.

Comment: Thanks this seems good and will work for me, and also will not have trouble if i need to change the authentication code.

Comment: @SumitPMakwana : Yes. It's power of Core-PHP. when you are following your own style. It will help you alot.

Comment: You forgot the exit() after header

Answer (score 0):

I usually just set a session like this once the user logs in:

```
$_SESSION['loggedIn'] = TRUE;
```

Then just check if `TRUE` or `FALSE` when needed.

ex:

```
if($_SESSION['loggedIn']){
    //Something here
} else{
    //Don't do it
}
```

Comment: Your technique is also much same as me, you just store true/false and I store username.

But is there something in PHP like filter in java?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with Java

Comment: or should I make file like auth.php which contain the code to redirect and then include it in all pages where required?

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing your architecture. However, I use a user controller class that sets the session to true upon login. Then I simply check for various states as needed. i.e. `<?php if($userDetails['customerStatus']!="active"){ ?>`

Answer (score 0):

It is depend on you architecture. If you are using any framework, like symfony you don't need to handle these for each and every page. I guess you are using pure PHP without any framework support. So you need to check whether the user is authenticated for each and every request by your own. I suggest you to without placing code segment related to logout in every page, just place it in a global function and call it in your every page. So that, if you want any simple change in that code segment, you can achieve it only changing that global function

Comment: I'm using pure PHP no framework, so should I make a file something like auth.php which checks the session and redirect if user is not logged in and then include it at top most part in each page which require authentication?